# ~ is $HOME, but sometimes?

Tags: cd-command, home

cd ~

does the same thing as

```
cd $HOME
```

which is also the same as

```
cd /home/tandu
```

However,

```
cd ~not-tandu
```

changes to `/home/not-tandu`

Is this purely a syntactic choice?  How is this handled by the kernel (or the `cd` execuable?)  Is there a special case for `~` to add the slash if everything else is omitted?  That is to say, `~/` and `~` change to the same directory, but `~a` is one directory up.  The same cannot be said for any other directory you change to.

Comment: Feel free to compare ~not-tandu and ~/not-tandu, one points to the user not-tandu home dir and the other points to the dir not-tandu in your homedir.

Comment: It's not the kernel or the "cd executable" (since there is no such thing) - it's a shell built-in.

Comment: Since you not mention it: `cd` without any parameters works like `cd ~`. If you replace `cd` with `echo` you can see to what the expression is expanded by the shell.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`~` is an alias for `$HOME` provided by a number of shells, but `$HOME` is more universal.  `$HOME` actually asks the shell to insert (substitute) the environmental variable HOME here.  There are quite a number of different environmental variable that can be substituted, try running `env` for a list.  Note that `~` is not always recognized when it's not at the beginning of a word.  Try these two commands for comparison:

```
ls /~
ls /$HOME
```

The first gets passed to the ls executable as `/~` which then tries to look at a file called `~` in the root directory, the second expands `$HOME` and becomes `//home/user` which is then passed to the ls executable as a command-line argument.  All POSIX systems (POSIX is the standard for how UNIX and Linux systems operate) allow multiple slashes to be treated the same as one slash so `//home/user` is the same as saying `/home/user`.  `~username` is a shortcut for telling the shell to look up username in the passwd file and return their home directory.  There is no equivalent environment variable.  All of these substitution are done by the shell and are supported by most of them, but only environment variables like `$HOME` are guaranteed to be supported by all shells.  Also, `cd` is actually a built-in command.  It's a special directive that tells the shell itself to change directories.  It's not like other shell built-ins that can be implemented as a separate executable like `echo` is because it's used to change a fundamental attribute of the shell process.  `echo` is merely a shell built-in for performance reasons, but in the good old days of UNIX, was only available as it's own executable `/bin/echo`.

Comment: re "which then tries to look at a file called ~ in the root directory"; That's for all unix flavors?

Answer (score 17):

`~foo` means 'the home directory of user foo'.

This isn't done by the kernel, it's interpreted by the shell. Whenever the shell sees `~foo` as an argument, it transparently replaces it with the home directory of user `foo` and passes that in its place. So when you run `cd ~tandu`, the shell is actually running `cd /home/tandu`.

Comment: What specifically does this replacement and with what algorithm?  Is it `cd` or the shell?  What if you are not running a shell?  Is it a simple "if ~ is followed by something, expand differently?" or is there some other special handling for this unique condition?

Comment: See the [Bash manual on Tilde Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html).  (Many other shells and programs follow similar rules.)

Comment: @tandu: the shell does `cd`, there is not external executable to do it (it wouldn't be possible)

Comment: @tandu: if you're not running a shell (e.g. trying this out using `exec(2)`), shell expansion doesn't take place. Without shell expansion, `~` doesn't get replaced by anything — it's just another perfectly valid character. This bit me in my early SunOS days because `/bin/sh` didn't grok `~`.

Answer (score 6):

`~` followed by a username expands to that user's home directory.