# What are the types of ~, ~-, ~+, *?

Tags: bash

If I am correct, `pwd` is a command, `PWD` is a variable('s name), and `-` in `cd -` is an operand.

What are the types of `~`, `~-`, `~+`, `*` when they mean `$HOME`, the previous visited dir, the current dir, and the files under current dir? (from programming languages' perspective)

Are they variables' names? If yes, why does `echo $~` not work?

Why does `*` work in:

```
for i in *; do ls "$i"; done
```

Comment: Please search the U&L site before asking such basic/fundamental Q's. Much of what you ask is covered throughout. For ex. tildes are discussed here: [Does ~ always equal $HOME](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146671/does-always-equal-home).& here: [~ is $HOME, but sometimes?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34379/is-home-but-sometimes) & here: [What is the “~/” directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61768/what-is-the-directory)

Comment: Also if you'd read the Bash manual there's an entire section devoted to tilde-prefixes, which is what these are called: [Bash Reference Manual - 3.5.2 Tilde Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is a metacharacter (or wildcard), all the other ones are `tilde-prefix` examples (`~` is standard, `~+` and `~-` are extensions).

None are variables so there is no point prefixing them with a `$`.

`echo $~` works fine, it displays `$~`. There is no expansion because `~` is not used as a prefix.

`for i in *; ...` works as designed.

Comment: Here they're discussed here in the Bash docs: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html